# Win7 : plink.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: git, plink

I can

```
git add.
git commit -m "first commit"
```

but cannot push

```
git push -u origin master
```

error:

> cannot spawn C:\Users\SEB\Downloads\plink.exe: No such file or
>   directory fatal: unable to fork

Comment: so... where did you hide plink.exe?

Comment: I have no idea what is plink.exe got to do with git? Any idea how to approach this Marc? Related to putty?

Comment: git isn't a single monolithic program. it's a set of tools for which git is the front-end.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. If there is an answer that was helpful for you then accept it

Comment: @niceseb as I said before if you have a new problem then create a new question.

Answer (score 4):

First ensure that you have an installed plink.exe. I recommend to install it to Program Files because your folder `C:\Users\SEB\Downloads\` is a bad place.

Then check your environment variable `GIT_SSH`. It should be something like:

```
GIT_SSH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\plink.exe
```

or

```
GIT_SSH=%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\plink.exe
```

This error also happened when there is a space in the `GIT_SSH` environment variable.

Comment: Have downloaded putty.exe and plink.exe again, then echo GIT_SSH but returns nothing

Comment: @niceseb so, just add it. If you do not want to install plink to the proper path then just create this variable and set C:\Users\SEB\Downloads\plink.exe

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to just run this, once per Windows session:

```
unset GIT_SSH
```